# Is there some where a list of the built-in functions for Swift?

Tags: cocoa-touch, swift

As I am new in Swift, quite often when I want to do a basic thing, I "recreate" functions which have actually already been created (built-in functions: sort, equals, find, contains, etc.) so I was wondering if you had a link with all those functions details and explications (with examples as well would be awesome!)

I found [this](http://practicalswift.com/2014/06/14/the-swift-standard-library-list-of-built-in-functions/) but it's quite old (june 2014) and not everything is documented.

Comment: http://swiftdoc.org/ - up to date to version 1.2

Comment: See this [blog post](http://practicalswift.com/2014/06/14/the-swift-standard-library-list-of-built-in-functions/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see everything that Swift provides “out of the box” by typing the name of a Swift built-in (like `String`), then command-clicking it.  Example:

[image: demo]

This takes you to a generated file declaring all of Swift's built-in types and functions. (The file does *not* exist in the Xcode bundle. It is generated on demand in memory from the file `Swift.swiftdoc`, which exists in several places in the Xcode.app bundle.)

Comment: Yes but you have to remember from which line to go to see the list of built-in functions and making a search in this huge file is not really practical as there are many "func contains" for example. Of course you can easily see that the func contains in the struc ClosedInterval is not the one you're looking for but if you have to check it all the time it's quite long. But thanks any way, I didn't realise those functions definitions where in the same file than "String"

Comment: The unfortunate fact is that Apple's Swift documentation is currently terrible (one of many reasons I recommend not using Swift for production code yet). You might find third-party attempts at documentation, but you won't find anything more up-to-date and complete (in the sense of mentioning all defined functions) than what I've demonstrated above.